# Inconsistent types between OpenGL calls

Tags: opengl, types

Something minor that's bugging me just now.  In OpenGL, when I want to allocate a name for, say, a buffer, I use the following function. Note the output type is *GLuint* (unsigned integer).

```
void glGenBuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint * buffers);
```

When I want to get the name of the item currently bound to a given target, I have to use this function:

```
void glGetIntegerv(GLenum pname, GLint * params);
```

, which returns an integer.  I find this somewhat confusing and inconsistent.  Am I missing a *glGetUintegerv* command?  Why is it done this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything, and as for reasons, you'd need to ask the commitee/Khronos about that, but my bet would be on legacy circumstances around `glGet`. If you feel particularly bad about casting all the time, you might want to write your own routine that accepts (or, saner, returns) an unsigned parameter and performs safe casting.

Comment: OK thanks Bartek.  As long as casting is the accepted method, then that's OK with me.

Comment: It is in a sense that `glGetInteger` can still return an number that will be an id.